# how to iterate through HTML elements and sum the values using for loop

Tags: javascript, html

i have an issue using for loop to sum the values through elements inside HTML by pressing button  but the code did not work correctly  also i tried to show alert a massage that says "**not a number**" but every time show the same massage once i press the button

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input class="inp" type="" placeholder="Enter  a Number " > 
     <input class="inp" type="" placeholder="Enter  elec" > 
     <input class="inp" type="" placeholder="Enter  food  " > 
     <input class="inp" type="" placeholder="Enter  car " > 
     <input class="inp" type="" placeholder="Enter  resturent " >
      
     <h1 class="total">total</h1>
     <button class="btn">calculate</button>
     <script 
        const btn= document.querySelector('.btn')
        const total = document.querySelector('.total')
        const inp = document.querySelectorAll('.inp')
    
    
    
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    
    if (isNaN(inp.value)) {
      alert("Not a number")
      console.log(inp.value);
    } if (inp.value === ""){
      alert("enter  number ")
    
    } 
    
     for (let i = 0; i <inp.length; i++) {
      let index = 0
      const current = index + inp[i].value 
       total.innerHTML = index
    
    }
    
    })
   </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "let index = 0" needs to be before the loop.

Comment: The default input type is text. Convert them into numbers if you want to use them for calculation otherwise isNaN will return true always

Comment: Also, inp will hold a collection of DOM elements so if you want to check value, you will have to iterate through inp.

Comment: as a side remark, it makes very little sense to have classes basically mapping to a corresponding tag. `<button class="primary">` will always make much more sense that `<button class="btn">` ...

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/52atj3f4/

Answer (score 0):

Change to input `type=number`. Also check with `typeof` if the variable is a number. If not, you can convert it with JavaScript function `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type of your inputs, then move your "validation" inside your loop, then
move your counter outside the loop and change it to "let", then cast to number the input value before sum into the current.

have a nice day

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="inp" type="number" placeholder="Enter  a Number ">
    <input class="inp" type="number" placeholder="Enter  elec">
    <input class="inp" type="number" placeholder="Enter  food  ">
    <input class="inp" type="number" placeholder="Enter  car ">
    <input class="inp" type="number" placeholder="Enter  resturent ">

    <h1 class="total">total</h1>
    <button class="btn">calculate</button>

    <script>
        let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            const total = document.querySelector('.total')
            const inps = document.querySelectorAll('.inp')
            let current = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < inps.length; i++) {
                if (isNaN(inps[i].value)) {
                    alert("Not a number")
                    break;

                } if (inps[i].value == "") {
                    alert("enter  number ")
                    break;
                }
                current += +inps[i].value
                total.innerHTML = current
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```